# Preview a font before it is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, fonts

I wish to preview a font file once it is chosen in an `<input type="file">` input.

I've tried an approach similar to that used to preview images (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded#4459419)), but using a [`Font` object](http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/Font.js/) instead of an `Image` object. However, the font fails to load after the `src` is set, because it searches for the font installed on the system, but by a temp name.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try appending some css to the doc (`@font-face` with `e.target.result` as the src property) ? `$('<style>@font-face{src='+e.target.result+';...</style>').appendTo($(document))` (won'tprobably work but worth testing i guess)

Comment: @mikakun It works, nice call! Please post it as an answer so I can give you the reputation you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there it is (although it was more a guess than an educated/tested answer) :

preview a font before it is uploaded (in modern browser) by using the fileReader class & appending to the document the read file object result property in a new `@font-face` css definition:

```
  function previewfonts(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('<style>'+
                     '@font-face{'+
                         'font-family: preview;'+
                         'src: url('+e.target.result+');'+
                      '}'+
                      '.preview {font-family: preview;}'+
                  '</style>'+
                  '<div class="preview">lorem ipsum...</div>').appendTo($(document));

            }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
     }
```